# Is there a way to get S3 usage statistics (like space utilized) using aws-sdk (node)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get the total size I'm utilizing on my S3 bucket programmatically.

I've looked into AWS-SDK methods to interact with S3 buckets but none of them allows us to fetch space utilization stats. I am not sure if cloudwatch API functions can be used to achieve this.

Edit: Tried using John's direction to translate into the node sdk I am using:

```
var params = {
    EndTime: new Date(), /* required */
    MetricName: 'BucketSizeBytes', /* required */
    Namespace: 'AWS/S3', /* required */
    Period: 3600, /* required */
    StartTime: '2019-06-07T00:00:00Z', /* required */
    Dimensions: [
        {
            Name: 'BucketName', /* required */
            Value: config.s3BucketName /* required */
        },
        {
            Name: 'StorageType',
            Value: 'StandardStorage '
        }
    ],
    Statistics: [
        'Average'
    ],
    Unit: 'Bytes'
};
cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

But all I get in return is a blank Datapoints array everytime. Tried to change dates and period, with no luck.

```
{ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' },  Label: 'BucketSizeBytes',  Datapoints: []}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **retrieve the size of each bucket from Amazon CloudWatch**.

From [Monitoring Metrics with Amazon CloudWatch - Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html):

> Metric: `BucketSizeBytes`
>
> The amount of data in bytes stored in a bucket. This value is calculated by summing the size of all objects in the bucket (both current and noncurrent objects), including the size of all parts for all incomplete multipart uploads to the bucket.

So, simply retrieve the metric from Amazon CloudWatch rather than calculating it yourself.

Here is the equivalent in an [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command, which you can translate into your preferred SDK:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics 
--namespace AWS/S3 
--metric-name BucketSizeBytes 
--dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=my-bucket Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage 
--start-time 2019-06-05T00:00:00Z 
--end-time 2019-06-05T01:00:00Z 
--period 3600 
--statistics Average
```

Result:

```
{
    "Label": "BucketSizeBytes",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2019-06-05T00:00:00Z",
            "Average": 17582395.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that there are three dimensions, based on storage type. The above is only showing `StandardStorage`.

To see what dimensions are available, use:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/S3
```

Comment: Ok, so due to an extra space in my StorageType param, I was getting all blanks. Started with your answer, fixed the typo, and now I am able to get what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you come across the empty data-points issue, ensure your date ISO string is initialised to midnight. Here is my Node SDK solution to get the total bucket size in MB:

```
function totalDataUsage() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let today = new Date();
    let yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() -1)

    yesterday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    startTime = yesterday.toISOString();
    endTime = today.toISOString();

    let params = {
        EndTime: endTime,
        MetricName: 'BucketSizeBytes',
        Namespace: 'AWS/S3',
        Period: 3600,
        StartTime: startTime,
        Dimensions: [
            {
                Name: 'StorageType',
                Value: 'StandardStorage'
            },
            {
                Name: 'BucketName',
                Value: 'your-bucket-name-here'
            }
        ],
        Statistics: ['Average'],
        Unit: 'Bytes'
    };

    cloudwatch.getMetricStatistics(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve((data.Datapoints[0].Average / 1000000).toFixed(1));
        }
    });
});

totalDataUsage().then(totalSizeMB => {
    console.log(totalSizeMB);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Total size of the S3 bucket,
`Amazon S3 Storage Lens` already can show you.

According to the link: Find out the size of the S3 bucket:

[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/find-out-the-size-of-your-amazon-s3-buckets/#:~:text=To%20find%20the%20size%20of,of%20bytes%20stored%20over%20time](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/find-out-the-size-of-your-amazon-s3-buckets/#:%7E:text=To%20find%20the%20size%20of,of%20bytes%20stored%20over%20time).

```
S3 Storage Lens is a tool that provides a single-pane-of-glass visibility of storage size and 29 usage and activity metrics across your Amazon S3 storage. 
With S3 Storage Lens, you get visibility at the AWS organizations or AWS account level, with drill-downs by region, storage class, bucket, and prefix.
```